# Gstreamer error when running Basic tutorials

Tags: gstreamer, raspbian

I'm having this error in [basic tutorial 1](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/hello-world.html?gi-language=c) of `Gstreamer`

```
:00:02.358297919  7270 0xb16041b0 ERROR         v4l2bufferpool gstv4l2bufferpool.c:679:gst_v4l2_buffer_pool_streamon:<v4l2vp8dec0:pool:sink> error with STREAMON 3 (No such process)
0:00:02.358521377  7270 0xb16041b0 ERROR         v4l2bufferpool gstv4l2bufferpool.c:2099:gst_v4l2_buffer_pool_process:<v4l2vp8dec0:pool:sink> failed to start streaming
```

and an equivalent error when runnig [basic tutorial 3](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/dynamic-pipelines.html?gi-language=c):

```
Pipeline state changed from NULL to READY:
0:00:01.089977824  7528 0xaf603f50 ERROR         v4l2bufferpool gstv4l2bufferpool.c:679:gst_v4l2_buffer_pool_streamon:<v4l2vp8dec0:pool:sink> error with STREAMON 3 (No such process)
0:00:01.090111951  7528 0xaf603f50 ERROR         v4l2bufferpool gstv4l2bufferpool.c:2099:gst_v4l2_buffer_pool_process:<v4l2vp8dec0:pool:sink> failed to start streaming
Received new pad 'src_0' from 'source':
It has type 'video/x-raw' which is not raw audio. Ignoring.
Received new pad 'src_1' from 'source':
Link succeeded (type 'audio/x-raw').
Pipeline state changed from READY to PAUSED:
Pipeline state changed from PAUSED to PLAYING:
Error received from element source: Internal data stream error.
Debugging information: ../subprojects/gstreamer/libs/gst/base/gstbasesrc.c(3072): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:test-pipeline/GstURIDecodeBin:source/GstSoupHTTPSrc:source:
streaming stopped, reason error (-5)
```

Tutorial 2 is running fine. 
I'm using Gstreamer 1.16 with [gst-build](https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-build) and Rasbbian Buster.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you don't have a VP8 decoder installed on that system. It tries to decode it on the hardware, but the Pi hast no hardware support for VP8. So you will need a software based decoder. Check your distribution for potential available packages.